# How do I change the value of a global variable across multiple functions

Tags: python, function, global

I'm altering the value of a global variable in my code but it reverts back to the original value each time. How can I fix this?

```
global a
a = 1

def F1():
  a = 2

def F2():
  print(a)

F1()
F2()
```

I get an output of 1 but I'm wanting it to be 2 as per the change in F1.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Python Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) for the rules for `local` and `global` variables.

```
a = 1

def F1():
  global a
  a = 2

def F2():
  print(a)

F1()
F2()
```

You are trying to modify the value of global `a` in `F1`, so you need to declare `a` as global there.